# how android recognize the difference between built in apps and third party apps

Tags: android

how android recognize the difference between built in apps and third party apps.
whats are the measures do it use to recognize.
thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming problem?

Comment: yes, Actually I am working on app that will auto answer the call programatically, but the API for this is not working in Android2.3, by some initial investigation came to know that it was removed due to some security issue.. but it is allowed if we can do modification in Phone application of android, but I want to acheive it through my app only.. so just want to know that if its allowing through bulit in then why its not allowing from my app ??   and want to know what are the measures that it will take that perticular API call is from built in or third party APP...

Answer (score 0):

An app is recognized by the package it uses. All built-in apps have a common starting package name (Eg: com.android.... or com.htc...) not sure how identification between apps is of application :P